# Upper Bound for distance-two chromatic number in terms of maximum degree

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring, upper-bounds

Let us consider simple,finite, undirected graphs. A distance-two colouring of a graph $G$ is a function $f:V(G)\to\{1,2,\dots\}$ such that $f(u)\neq f(v)$ whenever $dist_G(u,v)\leq 2$. A distance-two colouring of $G$ is equivalent to a (proper) colouring of the square graph $G^2$ of $G$. Obviously, at least $\Delta(G)+1$ colours are required for a distance-two colouring of $G$ (where $\Delta(G)$ denotes the maximum degree of $G$). Also, every graph $G$ admits a distance-two colouring with $\Delta(G)^2+1$ colours (by greedy colouring of $G^2$).
**Is there a better upper bound (at least for a restrcited graph class such as planar graphs) ?**
*Or, is it not possible to obtain an $o(\Delta(G)^2)$ uppderbound, even for reasonably large restricted graph classes?*

Note that with the help of entropy compression method, good bounds are obtained for acyclic/star chromatic numbers (and acyclic/star chromatic indices). But, this approach seems not to be of use for distance-two colouring. For example, distance-two colouring is a $(2,\mathcal{F})$-subgraph colouring in the terminology of [1] where $\mathcal{F}=\{P_3\}$; and using Theorem 1 of [1], we can only say that there is a constant $C\leq 64\times 3^3$ such that $C\Delta(G)^2$ colours suffices to produce a distance-two colouring of $G$.

[1] *Aravind, N. R.; Subramanian, C. R.*, [**Forbidden subgraph colorings and the oriented chromatic number**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-10217-2_9), Fiala, Jiří (ed.) et al., Combinatorial algorithms. 20th international workshop, IWOCA 2009, Hradec nad Moravicí, Czech Republic, June 28–July 2, 2009. Revised selected papers. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 978-3-642-10216-5/pbk). Lecture Notes in Computer Science 5874, 60-71 (2009). [ZBL1267.05111](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1267.05111).

Comment: I am aware of Wagner's conjecture, and asking for proved results.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta$ denote the maximum degree of $G$.

The bound $\Delta^2+1$ cannot be improved significantly.
For instance, even for a colouring variant called 2-ranking (which is a generalisation of distance-two colouring), the number of colours required is $\Omega(\Delta^2/\log \Delta)$ [1].

Given below is a quote from a dynamic survey [2] of Cranston
(the notation $\chi^2(G)$ is replaced by $\chi(G^2)$ for clarity).

> Greedy coloring shows that $χ(G) \leq ∆ + 1$ for all $G$. Since $G^2$ has maximum degree at most $∆^2$ , we immediately have $χ(G^2) ⩽ ∆^2 + 1$. Applying Brooks’ Theorem to $G^2$ shows that equality holds for a connected graph $G$ only if $G^2 = K_{∆^2+1}$ . Hoffman and Singleton [100] famously used linear algebra to show this is possible only if $∆ ∈ \{2, 3, 7, 57\}$.
> This proof is also outlined in [147, Section 3.1]. The unique realizations for $∆ = 2$ and $∆ = 3$ are the 5-cycle and the Petersen graph. For $∆ = 7$, the only realization is the Hoffman-Singleton graph [100]. For $∆ = 57$, the question of whether any realization exists remains a major open problem.

### References

[1] *Almeter, Jordan; Demircan, Samet; Kallmeyer, Andrew; Milans, Kevin G.; Winslow, Robert*, [**Graph 2-rankings**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00373-018-1979-4), Graphs Comb. 35, No. 1, 91-102 (2019). [ZBL1407.05186](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1407.05186).

[2] *Cranston, Daniel W.*, [**Coloring, list coloring, and painting squares of graphs (and other related problems)**](https://doi.org/10.37236/10898),  [ZBL07727365](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07727365).

Comment: The graphs $G$ for which $G^2=K_{\Delta^2+1}$ are precisely the Moore graphs of diameter 2.